# PHP How to make a function accessible with and without the call in the same file?

Tags: php, ajax, function

Sorry if my question is not clearly understandable, I don't know how to express well what I want to say in English.

This is not a problem with code per se, as it is working as shown, but mostly a doubt of the behaviour of PHP.

When I call a function from another php file, it seems to read the function itself i.e. `function loademp(){}`
however, if I access the file containing the function from an ajax, it seems to need a call to the function i.e `loademp()` to be in the same file.

Since I had this issue I ended having this code in order to make it work from both origins, with the call for the ajax inside an if condition, otherwise it would be called twice from the php file:

```
<?php
     if ($_POST['runFunct']=="loademp"){ //call from ajax needs 'loademp()' to access the function;
        loademp();
     }

    function loademp(){ //loaded from another file apparently.
        try{
           //PDO code
           print_r(json_encode($results));
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e;
        }   
    }
```

My other file just look like this:

```
require __DIR__.'loademp.php';
loademp();
```

Isn't there a more practical way to just use the code for both cases with no conditioning depending on the origin? Since I can't call a specific function from ajax without the use of POST variables, I guess this is the best case for it, but I would appreciate if you could point out the good practices about it.

Comment: As long as you include the file that contains the function before trying to call it, it should work. Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: It is really quite hard to understand, what actual problem you are trying to fix here. What is stopping you from doing `require __DIR__.'loademp.php';` in the first script as well, instead of declaring the function there again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your confusion here is between *defining* a function and *executing* a function.

To define a function, you write something like this:

```
function say_hello_world() {
    echo "Hello, World!\n";
}
```

This doesn't cause anything to happen immediately, it just defines *how* to do something. In this case, it's basically like saying:

> Whenever I ask you to "say hello world", output to the screen "Hello, World!\n"

To make something actually happen, you have to *execute* the function, which looks like this:

```
say_hello_world();
```

That's basically saying:

> Do the actions I gave you for "say hello world"

In your example, your file `'loademp.php'` *defines* a function called `loademp` - it says "whenever I ask you to 'loademp', here's what I want you to do". In your other file, you include that file, so the function is defined. Then, you run it with this line:

```
loademp();
```

An AJAX call is no different from any other page load, so you need to do the same thing there - first, *define* the function, or include the file that does; then, *execute* the function.

So, rather than calling `loademp.php` directly, you could call a PHP script like `define_and_execute_loademp.php` with exactly the lines you've mentioned:

```
require __DIR__.'loademp.php';
loademp();
```

Comment: My question is more about if there is a way to skip the "if", and be able to access either way the file, but as you say I could create a new php just to call the function. I don't know if the good practices are: A) Having a php for each stuff you want to do. B) Having a huge php full of functions C) Doesn't matter. I'm often worried about good practices as I believe I'm doing things the "wrong" way to achieve something.

Comment: @Germán I think this will naturally become clearer as you write more complex code. One of the main purposes of writing functions at all is for code which you want to _reuse in multiple places_, so commonly you will have files that _define_ lots of functions, and then other files which _execute_ those functions in different combinations, and with different parameters. (Incidentally, "php" isn't normally used as a noun - what you're calling "a php" is generally called "a PHP file"; you might confuse people if you use it differently.)

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip. English is not my main language and in mine by saying "a php" "a js" it would be understood that is a file. My bad. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.